# How to scan elements with pointer variable to an array

Tags: c, visual-studio, scanf

I am using visual studio 2012.

I am trying to implementing 2 stacks using a single array.

**My C code**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
 {
int arr[10], ch=1, *top1=&arr[0]-1, *top2=&arr[9]+1;


while(ch!=5)
{
printf("1. Push in Stack 1\n2. Pop from Stack 1\n3. Push in Stack 2\n4. Pop from Stack       2\n5.Exit");
scanf("%d",&ch);
    switch(ch)
    {
    case 1:
        if(top1+1 !=top2)
        {
        scanf("%d",*++top1);
        }
        else
        printf("stack is full");
break;
    case 2:
        if(top1 != &arr[0]-1)
        printf("%d",*top1);
        else
        printf("Stack is Empty");
break;
    case 3:
        if(top2-1 !=top1)
        {
        scanf("%d",*--top2);
        }
        else
        printf("stack is full");
break;
    case 4:
        if(top2 != &arr[9]+1)
        printf("%d",*top2);
        else
        printf("Stack is Empty");
break;
    case 5:
        return(0);
    }
}


return 0;

}
```

Code is running properly,    `scanf("%d",*++top1);` and `scanf("%d",*--top2);` are  not
taking input.

usage of scanf is correct or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` Requires  an address for second and third arguments

If you pass value rather than address, you will get following warning

```
 warning: format â%dâ expects argument of type âint *â, but argument 2 has type âintâ [-Wformat]
```

MOdify like this

```
scanf("%d",*++top1); ==> scanf("%d",++top1);  
scanf("%d",*--top2); ==> scanf("%d",--top2);
```

**EDIT**

Your POP Implementation is not correct

```
1. pop1 you need to decrement top1
2. pop2 you need to increment top2
```

Comment: yes, i forgot to add decrement nd increment top1 and top 2. it should b like `printf("%d",*top1--);` `printf("%d",*top2++);`

Comment: Yes.It should be, other wise it won't become pop(`Returns the top element on the stack AND remove it from the stack.` ) implementation of stack. this becomes peek (`Returns the top element on the stack but does not remove it from the stack.`) implementation of stack.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider warning seriously, you are overlooking:

```
warning: format ‘%d’expects type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

for line `scanf("%d", *++top1);` and `scanf("%d", *--top2);`.

Because `scanf()`  with `%d` format string accepts a address not the value. So for example value of expression `*++top1` is treated as address that is not a valid address hence this causes  undefined behavior at runtime. Remove dereferencing `*` pointer in `scanf()` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In `scanf()`, you need to pass only address of memory where input is stored.

But you are dereferencing it .

For example.

change

```
scanf("%d",*++top1);
```

to

```
scanf("%d",++top1);
```